# Python Import error even with __init__.py file

Tags: python

I have 3 directories under S1

```
S1
   - D1
       --python1.py
   - D2
       --python2.py
   - D3
       --python3.py
```

In python3.py module, I have a statement(below) to import python2.py

```
import D2.python2
```

when I run python3.py I get a error " No module named D2.python2"

How can I fix this issue?

Note: I have `__init__.py` in all the directories to signify packages.

Comment: Is S1 on your module search path?

Comment: i think you have to write `from .. import D2.python2`, but a python program cannot import from higher directories than the directory it was started, so python3 (with the python2-import-statement) has to be importet from a file in s1 (or higher)

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure your `S1` directory is on your python [module search path](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path) so that the interpreter knows how to load it.

The easiest way is to add it to your `PYTHONPATH` environment variable.

Comment: Is it not easier to put the D1-, D2- and D3-directories in the site-packages?

Comment: Given `D*` have interdependencies it seems like `S1` is intended to be one package; so I'd rather put `S1` in there than the sub-packages. Either way, putting personal code in site-packages ties it unnecessarily to one particular python install in my opinion, making it hard to use virtualenv and just generally inconvenient. I'd rather use `PYTHONPATH`, or if intended to be available systemwide add a symlink into site-packages rather than just installing it there.